# Django : Page not found (404) Why...?

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner Django. So I read the tutorials and I'm following them.
But I'm receiving an Error page. 'What is the problem...?'
(I installed the python 3.6.5 version)

My error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL 
patterns, in this order:
1.polls/
2.admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

polls/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

And Finally!!
mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

But running `python manage.py runserver` gives this error:

> Page not found !!, The empty path didn't match any of these!!!

So I need your help, plz help me....!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `mysite` is the "Django project name", so it contains the *root* `urls.py`. If we take a look at the file, we see:

```
#  mysite/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

So that means that all the `urlpatterns` in the `polls/urls.py` are "sub URLs" of this `path('polls/', ...)`, therefore you can say that the URLs in `polls/urls.py` are "*prefixed*" with `'polls/'` implicitly.

In order to reach the `index(..)` view, we thus have to find a "path" from the *root URLs* to this specific view. The only way to reach this is first taking the `'polls/'` path, and then selecting the `''` path in `polls/urls.py`. The path is thus `polls/`.

So in order to "trigger" this view, you need to query a URL like:

```
https://localhost:8000/polls/
```

(of course if you have specified another port, or run the Django webserver on another server, you need to modify `localhost`, and `8000` accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this error and figured out that I misinterpreted the instruction at the top of page 18, section 2.3.4, listing 10. I modified that mysite/usrls.py file at the top level mysite directory, instead of the mysite/mysite/urls.py file. It worked fine after that.